# Why is comparing an integer with array of length 1 returns true while false with array of length 2 or more?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is comparing 0 with an array of length 1 returns true whereas it returns false for array length of 2 or more ?
For example,

```
var a=[]  //undefined
0<a  //returns false
a.push(1) // [1]
0<a // returns true
a.push(2) // [1, 2]
0<a // return false
a.push(3) // [1, 2, 3]
0<a // return false
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you get a implicid type conversion, first [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString#Description),

> The [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) object overrides the `toString` method of [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). For Array objects, the toString method joins the array and returns one string containing each array element separated by commas.
>
> JavaScript calls the `toString` method automatically when an array is to be represented as a text value or when an array is referred to in a string concatenation.

like `join` works and then it is converted to number.

> ```
> what you do   what you get  result  array        string      number
> ------------  ------------  ------  ---------    --------    ----------
> var a = [];
> 0 < a         0 < 0         false   []        -> ''       -> 0
> a.push(1);
> 0 < a         0 < 1         true    [1]       -> '1'      -> 1
> a.push(2);
> 0 < a         0 < NaN       false   [1, 2]    -> '1,2'    -> NaN
> a.push(3);
> 0 < a         0 < NaN       false   [1, 2, 3] -> '1,2,3'  -> NaN
> ```

Comment: Do you have a reference that JavaScript in this case first performs a conversion to string, and then to number?

Comment: Obligatory [jsF*** explanation](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/bidding-on-security)

Comment: @trincot, in ECMA 262 V 6 [7.2.11
Abstract Relational Comparison](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison), it tries to get a primitive value first, which is reached by toString.

Comment: @NinaScholz Note PreferredType there which seems to be number.

Comment: @PankajShukla, right. after converting to string, you get the numerical value.

Comment: @NinaScholz To me conversion to string first, looks not required and literature also seems to suggest that way. In fact if you take out string column you still get the same result. What's your view?

Comment: @PankajShukla, for getting a primitive value, it goes over toString, then to number.

Answer (score 4):

The comparison between a number and an array will trigger a type conversion. The EcmaScript specification sets out the rules for this in [section 7.1.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber). According to these rules, the number is not converted to another data type, but the object (an array is an object) will be subject to a conversion that goes like this:

> 1. Let *primValue* be ToPrimitive(*argument*, hint Number).
> 2. Return ToNumber(*primValue*).

The `ToPrimitive` function is described in [section 7.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive):

> 4. Let *exoticToPrim* be GetMethod(*input*, @@toPrimitive).

`@@toPrimitive` is a Symbol, which you access as [`Symbol.toPrimitive`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-symbol.toprimitive). The thing is that `Array` does not have this property, and so the process continues with this step:

> 8. Return OrdinaryToPrimitive(*input,hint*).
>
> When the abstract operation OrdinaryToPrimitive is called with arguments O and hint, the following steps are taken:
>
> 3. If *hint* is "**string**", then
>        a. Let *methodNames* be «"**toString**", "**valueOf**"».
> 4. Else,
>        a. Let *methodNames* be «"**valueOf**", "**toString**"».

As the *hint* is "**number**", we are in the second case. The next steps explain that these methods are applied in order.

Now, `Array.prototype.valueOf` just returns the array itself, so the following sub-step will not return, since the Type *is* Object (namely Array).

> 5.c.iii If Type(*result*) is not Object, return *result*.

As a consequence the fallback kicks in, and `toString` is called on the Array.

So the array is converted to string. This is the result of the first of the two steps listed at the top:

> 1. Let *primValue* be ToPrimitive(*argument*, hint Number).
> 2. Return ToNumber(*primValue*).

The second step is easier: the string is then converted to number, which is described in [section 7.1.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type).

As the `Array.prototype.toString` method creates a comma-separated list, these strings become certainly invalid numbers as soon as an array has more than one element. As mentioned in the specs, the return value then is `NaN`.

Any `<` comparison with `NaN` returns `false`, which explains the output you get.

Answer (score 1):

if you check the array as a number after each of the lines above it gives you the answer you are after.
Remember javascript does some typecasting during comparison

```
Number(a); //insert this after each line
```

Comment: And why does `push(2)` and `push(3)` returns `NaN`?

Comment: `console.log(a.toString(), Number(a.toString())`

Answer (score 1):

In a loosely typed language like JS you have to pay attention to how a mutable type like an array coerces into an immutable type. Basically `[1,2]` becomes `"1,2"`.

So `[1,2] == "1,2" // <- true`

Comment: It is not really related to whether a value is immutable or not. Even when an array is made immutable with `Object.freeze` you'll get this kind of coercion.

Comment: Yes you are right. What I've meant was the type coercion is towards the immutable type.

Comment: I think you mean "primitive", not so much "immutable". There are immutable objects as well, and coercion is not towards them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the `lenght` of the array, use `a.length`.

Answer (score 0):

In JS if you have only 1 element in your array, js will count his value like the element, in your case - number.
for example:

```
var b[]
b.push(8);
b == 8 //true (but b === 8 is false!)
```

And if you have more then 1 element in the array, the array type is array[number] and this is diffrent from number and because of that you can't compare it to a number.

Thats why in you code after you do:

```
var a=[]  
0<a  
a.push(1) 
0<a
```

You get true becuase the a value is now "1" and that bigger then 0. But, after the next push the value is [1,2] and its not a number (NaN) and thats why you get false.

Answer (score 0):

For comparisons, javascript tries to convert operands into number usually(preferred).

Look at this example:

```
console.log("test" == true);//false
console.log("test" == false);//false
```

Why? because "test" is attempted to be converted into Number so Number("test") gives NaN and NaN is not equal to either true or false.
Similarly,

```
0<a becomes 0 < Number(a) becomes 0 < 0 returns "false".
```

As a special case, when array has one element, `Number` is able to coerce that to a number but when you add more than one element, what number should be returned?
In that case, Number(arr) becomes NaN and again 0 is not less than NaN.