# Why for a single element array, we can directly use the array name to access the element?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = [10];
console.log("a = %d", a);  ---> Printed a = 10
var a = [10, 20];
console.log("a = %d", a);   ---> Printed a = NaN
```

Why for a single element array, we can directly use the array name to access the element?

Comment: looks related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314143/why-is-comparing-an-integer-with-array-of-length-1-returns-true-while-false-with/44314391#44314391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that [formatter `%d`](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter), you're asking to output an integer.

`[10] == 10)`, in JavaScript, return `true`. So, an integer and array that only has the same integer are equivalent. Also, `Number([10])` returns the number `10`. `Number([])` returns `0`. `['a'] == 'a'` also returns true. But `String(['a'])` returns the string `['a']`.

`[10, 20]`, though, doesn't have an equivalent integer. It can't be converted to an integer: `Number([10])` returns `NaN`. That's why you get `NaN` (i.e.: not a number).

You find in the Ecma Standard how [types are converted to numbers](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#table-tonumber-conversions). Notice that [array's type is Object](https://www.w3schools.com/JS//js_typeof.asp).

In conclusion: that happens, because you're asking for an integer and way arrays are converted to numbers in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Placing an array into string context will implicitly call `toString` on it (which, for an array, is along the lines of `this.join(",")`.

If the array contains one number, then the resulting string will be a value you can parse as a number.

If the array contains multiple numbers, then it won't.

```js
console.log("a = %s", [10]);
console.log("a = %s", [10, 20]);

console.log(Number("10"));
console.log(Number("10,20"));
```

Answer (score -2):

Array is a continious memory location.
When we define an array as arr=[a,b,c]; then the memory refernce of the first element is stored in arr.
If there is only one element in an array (arr=[5]) so arr will be storing the reference of the memory location where '5' is present.
And if there are more than one element then we need to provide the element number.

Comment: No, this is not at all how arrays work in Javascript.

Comment: What about `console.log("a = %d", []);`? Or `const a = [[], 1]; console.log("a = %d %d", a[0], a[1]);`? Or `console.log("a = %s", ['a']);`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).